# Complex Hermite polynomial orthogonality on weighted space

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

Consider the "probabilist's" Hermite polynomials given by $$H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\partial_x^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$

These polynomials trivially extend to functions of $w\in\mathbb{C}$. While working with them, I noticed the following orthogonality identity:

$$\iint_{\mathbb{C}}H_k(w)H_n(i\overline{w})e^{-\frac{1}{2}w^2-\mathrm{Im}(w)^2}\,dx\,d\xi=0$$ where $w=x+i\xi$ and $k\neq n$.

I have a proof but it is very roundabout (using the FBI transform). Is there a simple direct proof of the identity somewhere, or else a transformation to a more well-known orthogonality identity (with reference)?

Comment: just to be sure, in the exponent it says ${\rm Im}(w)^2$, is that the imaginary part of $w^2$ or the square of the imaginary part of $w$?

Comment: The square of the imaginary part.

Answer (score 5):

Fix $\xi$ and assume $k>n$ (the other case is similar). Integrate over $x$. You'll get $\int_{\mathbb R+i\xi}H_k(z)P_n(z-i\xi,\xi)e^{-z^2/2-\xi^2}\,dz$ where $P_n$ is some polynomial of 2 variables of degree $n$ with complex coefficients, so for fixed $\xi$, it can be written as a polynomial of degree $\le n$ in $z$. Now just shift the contour back to the real line and use the fact that $H_k$ is orthogonal to *every* polynomial of degree $\le n<k$ with the weight $e^{-x^2/2}$. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In [Complex Hermite polynomials: their combinatorics and integral operators](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2015-143-04/S0002-9939-2014-12362-8/S0002-9939-2014-12362-8.pdf)
 the following general orthogonality relation is proven:

[image]

Here the Hermite polynomials are defined with factors $e^{\pm x^2}$ instead of $e^{\pm x^2/2}$.

Not quite the relation in the OP, yet....